# Haml alphabetizes attributes. Can you override that?

Tags: haml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserve attribute ordering in Haml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766240/preserve-attribute-ordering-in-haml)

When you write in Haml:

```
%meta{'name' => '#', 'content' => '#'}
```

it becomes:

```
<meta content="#" name="#">
```

Haml alphabetizes the attributes. How do you override this?

Comment: I think there is no way, because it necessary what goes first.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to sort them? From a quick look through [the haml documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#attributes) it doesn't look like you can.

Comment: @chadoh Thank you for that definitive link, evidently it can't be done. I feel the need to sort them in cases where there are many attributes and I want to see the ones most relevant to my work first in the list. It is more expedient when I visually search the generated markup in a browser to have the most interesting attributes first. In addition to reducing visual markup clutter for the person who may have to read the generated output (me), I find some orderings more aesthetically pleasing than others.

Comment: Older versions of Ruby used to sort hashes alphabetically, so Haml still does it for backwards compatibility. God knows why.