# Preserve attribute ordering in Haml

Tags: haml

If I create an XML element in HAML:

```
%tag{:b => "b", :a => "a"}
```

I get this output:

```
<tag a="a" b="b"/>
```

Is it possible to keep the ordering of the attributes in HAML?

I need this for a client-side code to display values in certain order and don't want to pass extra information on the client just to maintain ordering.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with HAML because it's a hash.

Comment: Actually, Ruby's Hash class preserves order since Ruby 1.9, so that shouldn't be a problem.